# Client added new sandbox for Dynamics 365, and when trying to insert data I'm getting a 401 error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm

We had our client create a new sandbox for us to test imports without workflows (imports work on the original sandbox.) I'm authenticated into D365 using an Active Directory app with a certificate sent from the C# code and my thought process was to just replace all instances of the old base url of `{sandbox-name}.api.crm.dynamics` or `{sandbox-name}.crm.dynamics` with `{new-sandbox-name}.api.crm.dynamics` and `{new-sandbox-name}.crm.dynamics`. I'm getting a 401 error now when trying to import data.

I can't find in the Active Directory app where the certificate that we created is tied only to that original sandbox url, so is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new Sandbox D365 CRM, go and create the Application user in system user table with the right security role/privilege. Then it should work.

[image]

[Read more](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2021/09/21/setting-up-an-application-user-in-dynamics-365)

Comment: Create this in D365 or in Azure? The above looks like Azure.

Comment: @jmath412 nope, its new PowerApps maker portal, if you are familiar with classic UI, then in settings - Security - Users will also do this. I have added the link at the bottom as "Read more", pls refer it

Comment: I looked at users for the old sandbox versus the new, and they are both the same.

Comment: I reran the program and it worked with just changing the name of the sandbox as before. The only thing I can think of is some sort of VS caching. I'll accept your answer, because I know that'll help someone in the future who may not have the same users applied to new D365 instances. Thank you sir!